Python 3.13 REPL with vim or emacs key bindings?
I just upgraded to Python 3.13 and found that the vim key bindings that I had set up via readline and ~/.editrc, which worked in previous releases of the Python REPL, no longer work. Is there some way to get vim (or emacs) key bindings to work in the new REPL?

It looks like I have already found the answer, in PEP 762 – REPL-acing the default REPL.
It explains in the Rationale section that the designers of the new REPL made a trade-off: to sacrifice  configurability in order to gain features newly implemented from scratch, such as multi-line editing. For example, you can now hit up-arrow and edit a whole multi-line Python statement instead of hitting up-arrow to get just one line of a previously entered statement. This would be too hard to interface with readline and editline, which are relatively complex and call for features that are not implemented in PyREPL.
